# AWS CDK Aurora Serverless PostgreSQL - CloudWatch log export issue

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I am deploying an AWS Aurora serverless PostgreSQL database using AWS CDK. I've encountered an issue where I'm receiving the following error:

```
Aurora postgres Serverless currently doesn't support CloudWatch Log Export.
```

My configurations for creating DBCluster are:

```
"rdsClusterParameterGroupFamily": "aurora-postgresql13",
"rdsClusterParameter": {
    "pgaudit.log": "ddl,write"
},
"rdsClusterNewSubnetGroup": true,
"rdsClusterDeletionProtection": true,
"rdsClusterEngine": "aurora-postgresql",
"rdsClusterEngineVersion": "13.7",
"rdsClusterCopyTagsToSnapshot": true,
"rdsClusterStorageEncrypted": true,
"engineMode": "serverless",
"scalingConfiguration": {
    "autoPause": false, 
    "minCapacity": 4, 
    "maxCapacity": 32, 
    "secondsUntilAutoPause": 300
},
"customDBBackup": false,
"rdsClusterEnableCloudwatchLogsExports": ["postgresql"]
```

I suspect this issue might be related to the Aurora engine version. Any insight or guidance on the correct engine version or any necessary configurations would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried different version greater than 11.12 as per this official doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.CloudWatch.html